# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: cannot read "style" - How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Ive got this js error in my console, but I cant seem to find out what actually is wrong. Am I missing something? Would love some help on how to fix this. Ive got another version without "mobile" on all names and that one seems to work just fine.

This is the error:

```
scriptMobile.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at clearAllMobile (scriptMobile.js:26)
    at SVGGElement.LaksevagFunctionMobile (scriptMobile.js:43)
```

Ive added a comment at the right lines, according to the error:

JS:

```
function clearAllMobile(){
  // Clear Laksevag  
  document.getElementById("LaksevagMobile").style.opacity = "1"; //THIS IS LINE 26
  document.getElementById("Laksevag-H-Mobile").style.opacity = "0";
  // Clear Fana
  document.getElementById("FanaMobile").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("Fana-H-Mobile").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("Fana-H-Mobile").style.zIndex = "0"
  // Clear Landas
  document.getElementById("LandasMobile").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("Landas-H-Mobile").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("Landas-H-Mobile").style.zIndex = "0";
  // Clear Fyllingsdalen
  document.getElementById("FyllingdalenMobile").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("Fyllingdalen-H-Mobile").style.opacity = "0";
}



function LaksevagFunctionMobile() {
  clearAllMobile() //THIS IS LINE 43
  resetActiveMobile()
  lastSelectedMobile = "LaksevagMobile";
  document.getElementById("LaksevagMobile").style.opacity = "0";
  document.getElementById("Laksevag-H-Mobile").style.opacity = "1";
  route.innerHTML = LaksevagBox.route;
  distance.innerHTML = LaksevagBox.dist;
  time.innerHTML = LaksevagBox.time;
  otherinfo.innerHTML = LaksevagBox.info;

  //button toggles
  DetailsBtnMobile.addEventListener("click", LaksevagDetailsMobile);
  InfoBtnMobile.addEventListener("click", LaksevagInfoMobile);

  function LaksevagInfoMobile() {
    document.getElementById("info-innerMobile").style.opacity = "1"
    document.getElementById("details-innerMobile").style.opacity = "0"
    document.getElementById("laksevag-detMobile").style.opacity = "0"
  }

  function LaksevagDetailsMobile() {
    document.getElementById("info-innerMobile").style.opacity = "0"
    document.getElementById("details-innerMobile").style.opacity = "1"

    document.getElementById("laksevag-detMobile").style.opacity = "1"
    document.getElementById("fyllingdalen-detMobile").style.opacity = "0"
    document.getElementById("landas-detMobile").style.opacity = "0"
    document.getElementById("fana-detMobile").style.opacity = "0"
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
#FanaMobile, #FyllingdalenMobile, #LaksevagMobile, #LandasMobile {
    opacity: 1;
}

#Fana-H-Mobile, #Fyllingdalen-H-Mobile, #Laksevag-H-Mobile, #Landas-H-Mobile {
    opacity: 0;
}

#FanaNameMobile, #FyllingdalenNameMobile, #LaksevagNameMobile, #LandasNameMobile {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: your `document.getElementById("LaksevagMobile").style.opacity` selector returns null

Comment: That usually means that the element with the id `LaksevagMobile` has not been found, thus the result is `null` and that value has no property called `style`. Check if the element exists on the page or that you have a typo in your `getElementById` call.

Comment: It might be that your document is not fully loaded, try something like: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)`, which fires everytime your document gets **entirely** loaded.

Comment: Because you have not posted the html, the above are good guesses, but we can't know since we don't have the entire picture. Also you should not put even listener creations inside a function, you will cause duplicated listeners.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. It turns out that Emiel was right. It was basically a typo in the HTML id and another one somewhere else in the javascript that made it not function.